# x3::symbols moves result and therefore removes it from the symbol_parser itself

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

So, I ran into strange behaviour with boost::spirit::x3 as supplied in boost 1.59:

I defined a 'dynamic' symbol table via:

```
struct instructions : x3::symbols<OpCode> {
    instructions()
    {
        name("instructions");
    }

    void set_instruction_set(const std::unordered_map<std::string, OpCode>& instruction_set) {
        for (const auto& var : instruction_set) {
            add(var.first, var.second);
        }
    }
} instructions_parser;
```

`OpCode`is defined as

```
struct OpCode
{
    std::string mnemonic;
    std::vector<...> variants;// actual type in vector<> not important.
};
```

now, with the symbol table embedded in the neccessary rules, when parsing an input string like

```
mov r2  r1
mov r1  @80
```

the resulting ast only contains the first `mov` with its operands.
The second mov is missing but the operands are correctly parsed.
This may look as followed, when printing the resulting AST:

```
mov r2 r1 
    r1 @80
```

With the debugger I located the source of the error in symbols.hpp in `symbol_parser::parse()`:

```
template <typename Iterator, typename Context, typename Attribute>
    bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last
      , Context const& context, unused_type, Attribute& attr) const
    {
        x3::skip_over(first, last, context);

        if (value_type* val_ptr
            = lookup->find(first, last, get_case_compare<Encoding>(context)))
        {
            x3::traits::move_to(*val_ptr, attr); //<- the error originates from here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

with `move_to` beeing:

```
template <typename T>
inline void move_to(T& src, T& dest)
{
    if (boost::addressof(src) != boost::addressof(dest))
        dest = std::move(src);
}
```

As you can see, the `src` which is my OpCode instance added in the symbol_parser is moved. This means after the first call its empty again and that's why only the first instructions appears. It's, simply put, moved out of the symbol table.

**Now finally my question:**
Is this a bug or am I making a mistake?

Comment: [Seems to be a bug](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/XxPCnmWExNkmsmP2).

Comment: Thanks for providing the example. That is exactly the behaviour I experienced.
I found a temporary workaround:
By declaring the template parameter as const one can suppress move semantics. The copy-ctor is then called.
I.E.: x3::symbols<const std::string>

Comment: Could you please file the workaround as an answer and a bug at Boost Trac/a PR at github? Splendid observation!

Comment: Thanks for your response @sehe. I filed a bug in boost trac at https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12016
I'm not sure if I can file a PR. I'll have to investigate a proper fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by sehe my workaround as an answer:

I found a temporary workaround: By declaring the template parameter as const one can suppress move semantics. The copy-ctor is then called.

I.E.: `x3::symbols<const std::string>`